# Strange bug: Product[1/(1-1/2^(n-1)),{n,2,Infinity}] = 0?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

This infinite product is correct:

```
Product[1/(1 - 1/2^n), {n, 1, Infinity}]
(* 1/QPochhammer[1/2, 1/2] *)
```

Numerical value of this result is not equal to zero

```
N[1/QPochhammer[1/2, 1/2]]
(* 3.462746619455064 *)
```

But from following equivalent expression I get a wrong output:

```
Product[1/(1 - 1/2^(n-1)), {n, 2, Infinity}]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your final result, instead obtaining `1/(2 QPochhammer[1/2, 1/2])`, as it should be.

Comment: I can confirm this using: `10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)` with Windows 8.1

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I get `0/QPochhammer[2, 1/2]` on 10.3.1.

Comment: I get zero under versions 7.0.1.0, 8.0.4.0 and 10.2.0.0

Comment: I get zero under 10.0.1 on OS X10.10.5, but if we change `Infinity` to some large integer instead, it evaluates correctly.

Comment: Big persists through 10.4

Answer (score 8):

```
$Version

"10.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 9, 2015)"

p = Product[1/(1 - 1/2^n), {n, 1, Infinity}]

(*  1/QPochhammer[1/2, 1/2]  *)
```

Error:

```
Product[1/(1 - 1/2^(n - 1)), {n, 2, Infinity}]

(*  0/QPochhammer[2, 1/2]  *)
```

Workarounds:

```
Product[1/(1 - 1/2^(n - 1)), {n, m, Infinity}] /. m -> 2

(*  1/QPochhammer[1/2, 1/2]  *)

Limit[Product[1/(1 - 1/2^(n - 1)), {n, m, Infinity}], m -> 2]

(*  1/QPochhammer[1/2, 1/2]  *)

Product[1/(1 - 1/2^(n - 1)), {n, 2, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]

(*  1/QPochhammer[1/2, 1/2]  *)
```